# Splitting a vector into two

Tags: r, vector

How can I split a vector into two such that it selects a random sample for each new vector. But I always want to split in half. For instance

```
x <- 1:10
obj <- splitMyVector(x)

obj$a
 > 5 3 9 7 10
obj$b
 > 8 4 1 6 2
```

Note: the purpose for this is to do a split half reliability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
split(sample(x),letters[seq(length(x))%%2+1])
$a
[1]  9  7 10  4  2

$b
[1] 6 1 8 3 5
```

Comment: Nice.  You should point out that the `letters[...]` calculation isn't strictly necessary if the user is always going to use `a` and `b` for his factors. (Unless I'm not paying attention to the details here :-( )

Comment: Out of curiosity, may I ask what does the double '%%' operator do? I tried to Google for it but couldn't find any relevant results.

Comment: @130490868091234 It gives the remainder of integer division